# How to expands a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to analyze some ig comments. I have a dataset which composed of username and comments like;

```
Username   Comment
userx      comment(not all)...
usery      comment(not all)...
```

As you can see comments ends with `...` and i can't see whole comments\

I want to expand the comment section doesn't matter how long it is I need to show the entire text in slides to my instructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
```

pandas will correctly auto-detect the width of dataframe and will display all columns in single line.

If you want all columns and all rows to be displayed as well use all of below

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```